# Laravel broadcast notification doesnt work. It keeps processing

Tags: laravel, broadcast, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel Notification via broadcast channel.

Other notifications works fine except for this one notification. It just stays on **Processing** status and doesn't get **Processed** after waiting for a couple of hours.

Here is a sample of the log that shows when running

```
php artisan queue:work redis --queue=default
```

---

```
[2021-06-20 03:03:18][KzdWk12nVnZ1kHW88SjVNF3QoLF7ZPUe] Processing: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
[2021-06-20 03:03:18][KzdWk12nVnZ1kHW88SjVNF3QoLF7ZPUe] Processed: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
[2021-06-20 03:02:39][eQowR72smPimD9jmOhzQ2cQOw3zVd9wF] Processing: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
[2021-06-20 03:02:39][eQowR72smPimD9jmOhzQ2cQOw3zVd9wF] Processed: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
[2021-06-20 03:04:13][JAFReaqFrbxXo9wn3LxbbOPIvgnLdCGK] Processing: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
```

I am using **redis** as the connection for the queue.
It works locally except in AWS ECS Cluster.
Are there any factors that causing it to not being **Processed**?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I managed to figure out that the one causing the process to fail its because I am passing an Eloquent model to the Notification class. I have converted the data to an array and the broadcast worked perfectly.

Realized that it's better to pass arrays to the ***toBroadcast*** function instead of eloquent object.